# how do i swap two words with each other in a string via a cipher? the programming language is in c

Tags: c

Let's do a generic substitution cipher.
You receive clear text and two encryption words.
If the plaintext character is in cipherword 1, you must replace it with the corresponding character from cipherword 2. If the plaintext character is in cipherword 2, you must replace it with the corresponding character from the cipherword encryption 1.

Example.
word1 = "abcdefghijlm"
word2 = "nopqrtuvwxyz"

That is, all 'a' of the text must be replaced by 'n', and all 'n' by 'a'
All 'h' must be replaced by 'v', all 'z' by 'm', etc.

text "my slipper"
output "zwavn pvwaryn"

Note that word1 may show punctuation, numbers, etc.
If word1 = "123!*ov"
and word2 = "456?-ouch"
all '!' will come '?' and vice versa.

[DS]

Prohibited:
line 1: lowercase, numbers and punctuation
line 2: cipher word1
line 3: cipher word2

Ex:

> > 

oops friend xarles 2nd
The
x
<<
opx xmigo axrles 2nd

> > 

my slipper
abcdefghijlm
nopqrtuvwxyz
<<
zwavn pvwaryn

Comment: Welcome to SO. What is your question? What did you do to complete your homework assignment? Where are you stuck? Please show your code together with input, expected output as well as real output. Read [The Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) and then edit your question accordingly.

Comment: Yes.  Please include your code as your explanation of the encryption rules do not seem to match up with your example output.  For example, how do you end up with more characters in your encrypted output than your text input?  When I built a test program according to your rules, "my slipper" was encrypted to "zl fyvccre".